# Synax error on db.close()

Tags: python, mysql-python

Im trying to use mysqldb in a python script.

Here is a part of the code from the script

```
cursor = db.cursor()

    sql = """INSERT INTO location(`name`, `lat`, `long`, `guid`, `image`, `date`)VALUES(%(name)s, %(lat)s, %(long)s, %(guid)s, %(image)s, %(date)s)"""

    try:
        cursor.execute(sql)
        db.commit()

db.close()
```

Im gettig a error on the db.close()

"db.close()
     ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

So any suggestions here?

Comment: Indentation? It should be indented to the same level as `try:`

Comment: you forgot `except` after `try`.

Comment: Are those the real quotes you're using? Backticks...

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `try` without `except`.

The proper way to ignore all errors is this:

```
try:
    cursor.execute(sql)
    db.commit()
except:
    pass

db.close()
```

Comment: Should the `db.close` be in a `finally`?

Answer (score 1):

The error is with the try: - it's looking for an except: prior to the db.close.

Answer (score 0):

You would make everyone live easier if you posted fully working examples.
I added some dummy code to you post to make it run

```
class fake:
    def commit(self,):pass
    def execute(self,sql):pass
    def close(self,):pass


db =fake()
cursor=fake()

if 1:
    sql = """INSERT INTO location(`name`, `lat`, `long`, `guid`, `image`, `date`)VALUES(%(name)s, %(lat)s, %(long)s, %(guid)s, %(image)s, %(date)s)"""

    try:
        cursor.execute(sql)
        db.commit()

db.close()
```

If I run this I get:

```
$ python3 test.py 
  File "test.py", line 17
    db.close()
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected unindent
$
```

Which is show you are missing the except clause in your example.

This isn't the error you report, perhaps you Syntax Error is in part of the code you haven't included in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the indentation errors in your code, you need to use either an `except` clause, a `finally` clause, or both with your `try` statement.

With a `finally` clause you can ensure that the db connection is closed:

```
try:
    cursor.execute(sql)
    db.commit()
finally:
    db.close()
```

In practice it is worthwhile including an `except` clause so that the exception can be logged:

```
import traceback

try:
    cursor.execute(sql)
    db.commit()
except Exception as exc:
    traceback.print_exc()    # or whatever logging you require
    raise                    # optionally re-raise the exception
finally:
    db.close()               # _always_ executed
```